# Self-type does not conform to base class

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, scala-generics

Using the following code:

```
trait Hello[B <: Baz[_, _]]
trait World[F <: Foo] { self: Hello[Baz[F, _]] =>

  def foo: F

}
trait Baz[F <: Foo, B <: Bar]
trait Foo
trait Bar

case class BasicHello() extends Hello[BasicBaz] with World[BasicFoo]
case class BasicBaz() extends Baz[BasicFoo, BasicBar]
case class BasicFoo() extends Foo
case class BasicBar() extends Bar
```

I get the following error in my IDE at the `BasicHello` case class:

```
Illegal inheritance, self-type BasicHello does not conform to Hello[Baz[F, _]]
```

I have no clue why the compiler doesn't allow this since `BasicHello` extends `Hello[BasicBaz]`, which in its turn extends `Baz[BasicFoo, BasicBar]`. The type of `BasicHello` should be `Hello[Baz[Foo, Bar]]` which is exactly what the `World` mix-in requires. Is there some hierarchical property I'm missing of self-types?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that `Hello` is invariant in `B`. So, `Hello[BasicBaz]` is not a subclass of `Hello[Baz[BasicFoo,BasicBar]]` even though `BasicBaz` is a subclass of `Baz`.

If you make `Hello` covariant in `B`, (`trait Hello[+B <: Baz[_,_]]`), then it'll compile.

Comment: If `Hello` cannot be made covariant, chaging the self-type annotation like so would also do the trick: `self: Hello[_ <: Baz[F, _]] =>`

Comment: Nice! Haven't thought of that.